# How to center align tab panel tabs

Tags: visualforce, css

say I have the following.

```
<apex:tabPanel  selectedTab="Tab 1"  >
            <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="Tab1" id="tabOne" />
            <apex:tab label="Tab2" name="Tab2" id="tabOne" />
            <apex:tab label="Tab3" name="Tab3" id="tabOne" />
</apex:tabPanel>
```

How do I center the tabs themselves? It seems to align left, and setting a style class for the tab panel doesn't seem to do anything.

[image: How do I center it like this?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Use headerAlignment attribute.

```
<apex:tabPanel headerAlignment="center">
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

use **header alignment**

```
<apex:page >

  <apex:tabPanel headerAlignment="center" selectedTab="Tab 1"  >
            <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="Tab1"  />
            <apex:tab label="Tab2" name="Tab2"  />
            <apex:tab label="Tab3" name="Tab3" /> </apex:tabPanel>

</apex:page>
```